# Handling nulls in JSON Merge Patch

Tags: json, rest, api, http, merge

I am using `application/merge-patch+json` as my content type to edit a resource via HTTP PATCH method. I got my data stored in an RDBMS.

The [merge patch spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7386) clearly states that when a key is set to a `null` value, it should be deleted from the resource.

This is impossible for me to do however, as I cannot simply delete columns in my DB for certain rows - the values I 'delete' are simply set to `null`, which goes against the spec.

I thought of two options:

1. Go against the spec and simply set the columns to `null`, keeping them in the resource
2. Use JSON patch instead, which is quite an overhead compared to merge patch

Is there some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DELETE` on an API resource doesn't have to be actually deleting the resource in the DB - it could be a soft delete for that matter (which is what you're doing, in fact).

As long as it's properly represented as deleted by the API (e.g. you can omit displaying null values - I think JSON does that for you by default), it can be argued that you're respecting the spec.

Answer (score 1):

The RFC doesn't define how you store your data, it's only about JSON.
API/Domain Models should be separated from Entity Layer / DB.
How you map between these two, is up to you.